Fetching user details in Laravel and displaying in Vue.js without using Axios
I have a table listing users, each with an onClick function button associated with their data id. When I click the button, it calls the function getUserDetails(1) to fetch data from a Laravel function, which then sends a response. After that, a popup opens with the data.
Here's my Vue function:
const response = ref([]);
const popup = ref(false);

const getUserDetails = (id) => {
  response.value = route.get(route('user.Details', {id: id})); // I think there might be a mistake here
  popup.value = true; 
}

I have a web route:
Route::get('/userDetails/{id}', [UserController::class, 'details'])->name('user.Details');

And here's my UserController:
public function details($id) {
  $userDetails = User::find($id);
  return $userDetails; // How should I return this? response()->json($userDetails) or something else?
}

Is there any other process that does not use Axios?

In your Vue function, you are correct that there is a mistake in how you are fetching the user details. You should use Axios or similar HTTP client libraries to make AJAX requests in Vue.js. However, if you prefer not to use Axios, you can use the built-in fetch API in modern browsers.
Here's how you can update your Vue function to use fetch:
import { ref } from 'vue';

const response = ref({});
const popup = ref(false);

const getUserDetails = (id) => {
  fetch(`/userDetails/${id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      response.value = data;
      popup.value = true;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching user details:', error);
    });
}

In your Laravel controller, you should return the user details as a JSON response:
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function details($id) {
        $userDetails = User::find($id);
        return response()->json($userDetails);
    }
}

With these changes, clicking the button associated with each user in your Vue app will fetch their details using the /userDetails/{id} endpoint in Laravel and display them in a popup or modal.
